# Odd-sounding usage of "whose"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Aside from the normal uses of ***whose***, i.e. for people, animals, or inanimate objects, can it also be used in regard to a motive, reasoning, or any other intangible attribute/characteristic of an action or decision?

e.g.

> Annually, egregiously lavish feasts are held in memory of his late father, which (is something) I don't understand.

Now, for the sake of concision, or a more literary approach, can it be paraphrased like this:

> Annually, in memory of his late father, egregiously lavish feasts are held, whose reasoning I don't understand.

(whose referring to the feast being held/the decision behind it, or even why people would attend)

Another example:

> To appease her fanbase, she started wearing black lipstick, which (is something) I don't understand.

Similarly:

> To appease her fanbase, she started wearing black lipstick, whose appeal I don't understand.

Meaning, I don't understand why people/her fanbase would be attracted to it. (whose referring to the allure of "black lipstick", and the excitement it provokes.)

It sounds a bit off, but I found myself using whose within similar contexts so as to completely convey my meaning within one formal statement. Is there any other way to question the appeal/reasoning behind an action or decision, which is more formal than the former statements (using *which* + *something*), but not as odd sounding as the substitutes?

Comment: In the "whose" version of your first example, "whose" seems to refer to the father. So you're saying that you don't understand the father's reasoning.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you. My original example was the "lipstick" one, but since it seemed a bit inappropriate, I chose to come up with a more serious one, and didn't think much about it. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Sure. You can use it with anything resembling a noun. In some cases, it would sound a bit awkward.

Comment: Formally it could be "the appeal of which" instead of "whose appeal". I am not aware af any other good alternative.

Comment: No. In both of your examples, the meaning between *which* and *whose* is different. And in the first one, *whose...* is misplaced; it should be:  *...lavish feasts, whose reasoning I don't understand, are held.*

Comment: Many students are wrongly cautious about using "whose", as they seem to think that the letters **w h o** are too strongly related to "who", which is used only for people. This is a mistake - "whose" is a general possessive and can be (and is) used for people, animate object, inanimate objects and abstracts. *"It is an idea whose time has come." / "The dog whose collar is red." / The man whose wife is ugly." / "The house whose roof is red." / The tree whose leaves have fallen.", etc.*

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you for the answer; however, I've never had any issues using _whose_ in the way you've explained and provided examples for – that is, using it for something other than a person. "This is an argument whose veracity is as of yet unclear." sounds fine to me. But this very same sentence structure (using whose + something abstract) could sound odd in another example, such as given above. So in a way, yes: I was wondering whether it'd be as natural to use "whose" for abstracts/actions/thoughts and the like since I don't see it used much that way.

Comment: @Andrew.V I think you might have confused yourself - **whose** can be an adjective/determiner "of whom", or "of which" - "The man whose coat is red." = The man the coat of whom is red."/ The idea whose time has come = The idea the time of which has come. / "Whose coat is this?" = "The coat/idea/wife/dog/tree of whom is this?" Or a pronoun: "Whose is this/that/the car/the wife/the dog/the idea?" = "Of whom is this/that/the car/the wife/the dog/the idea?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several pronouns, such "which", "that", etc., that have no possessive version. If you need to have a possessive version, you'll have to rely on "whose" (putting 's after a pronoun is not correct). However, if you can rewrite the sentence to avoid it, that may be preferable. For instance, for your second example, you can say "To appease her fanbase, she started wearing black lipstick, the appeal of which I don't understand." The problem with "whose" is that it can cause people to think that it refers to a person, rather than a thing. This makes your "whose" a poor choice in your first example, especially since "reasoning" applies to a person, not a thing. In that case, it would not be rewritten as "the reasoning *of* which", but rather "the reasoning *for* which".

Comment: Based on other comments, your answer, and my common understanding: "whose" is not strictly incorrect to indicate a possessive nature for things not _directly_ related to people or objects, but, if possible, it's best to rewrite the sentence using the following construction: "...The **(appeal/reasoning/motive)** **(of/for/behind)** which...".